# dynamically load images on scrollview

Tags: uiscrollview, titanium, appcelerator

Is there any efficient way to load images on scrollableview dynamically in Titanium Appcelerator? I want to load 200-300 images on swiping the scrollableview.

Comment: what have you tried so far? I have an app in the app store that can handle up to 250 images.

Comment: I tried this code http://pastie.org/1352978 but it doesn't work properly, also I couldn't understand the logic behind the selectedPage variable in that code. Can you pls help me out?

Answer (score 1):

this is the cleanest solution I have seen so far as a starting point. The approach I took for my application requires some refactoring before I post it.

https://gist.github.com/810171